# How to loop through an array in waiting a time between each item?

Tags: javascript, loops, asynchronous, promise

I have an array like this:

**`var items = [["text1", 3000],["text2",4000],["text3",1000]], ...a lot more here...;`**.

In the html side, we got `<div id="d"></div>`

Now, I want to print out "**text1**" on the div after 3000 milliseconds, the PC will then wait for 4000 milliseconds before printing "**text2**", then it will print out "**text3**" after 1000 milliseconds, so on until it finishes the loop.

I think we need to do with `setInterval` or something like that but it is too hard for me to think of it. Maybe a nested **setInterval**??

**So Given an 2-D array of text & millisecond-number, How to print each item out after a specified milliseconds?**

Note: I need to print out in the right order of `items`, that is it will print out text1 first, then text2, then text3, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**

Finally found the solution

```js
var items = [["text1", 3000],["text2",4000],["text3",1000]];

var time=0;
printElems(0);

function printElems(i){
 setTimeout(function(){
            var elem=document.getElementById("d");
            elem.innerHTML=items[i][0];
            if(items[i+1]!=undefined){
                printElems(i+1);
            }
 },items[i][1]);
}
```

```html
<div id="d"></div>
```

This will do the trick. What I have done here is, just sum the times and make **setTimeout** calls based on the delay.This loops through the array in the given order.

Comment: 1 small question, let say I have 2 'printElems(i)" function, I want when i run the 2nd one I want the first 1 got disabled. How to do that?

Comment: can we make "printElems(0, boolean);" or somethings liek that, so that when we "printElems(0, false);" it will disable the function

Comment: I found the solution, ...myVar=setTimeout... clearTimeout(myVar);

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, they will be printed from the shortest time to the longest time if you wrap a `setTimeout` (asynchronous) in a loop (synchronous).

To solve the problem you can use Promises.

Here is an implementation with [jQuery.Deferred](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.deferred/):

```
var dfd = $.Deferred().resolve();

items.forEach((item) => {
    dfd = dfd.then(() => print(item));
});

function print(item) {
    var dfd = $.Deferred();

    setTimeout(() => {
        $('#d').html(item[0]);
        dfd.resolve();
    }, item[1]);

    return dfd.promise();
}
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/y4pn0L06/)**</kbd>

Comment: why it didn't print item3?

Comment: also why it print out text3 first, then text2, then text1??? I want it print out text1, then text2, then text3

Comment: Yes you are right. I didn't think about it, but they are printed from the shortest time to the longest time since setTimeout is asynchronous.

Comment: so, how to fix the issue?

Comment: I'm working on it. Your problem is interesting actually. :)

Comment: also works, but are you sure jQuery.Deferred will work on all browser?

Comment: Yes it's even compatible with IE6. I took `jQuery.Deferred` because [JS Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Promise) don't work on IE.

Comment: Can we do like this **alert(3); defered(3000); alert(4); defered(4000); ...etc**

Comment: Also, let say I have 2 functions "print(item)". When I run the 2nd one, I want to cancel the first 1. and via versa. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

With promises, compactly:

```
function wait(ms) { return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms)); }

items.reduce((promise, [text, ms]) => 
    promise . then(() => wait(ms)) . then(() => console.log(text)),
  Promise.resolve());
```

With `setTimeout`, recursively:

```
function sequence(array) {
  if (!array.length) return;
  var elt = array.shift();
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(elt[0]);
    sequence(array);
  }, elt[1]);
}
```